# boost scoped unlock for a mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have a code that looks like:

```
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lck(mQueueMutex);

while (true)
{
    ...

    // unlock the queue while we exec the job
    lck.unlock();

    ...

    // lock the queue again
    lck.lock();
}
```

I am looking to do something like this:

```
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mQueueMutex);

while (true)
{
    ...

    // unlock the queue while we exec the job
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_unlock unlock(lock);

        ...
    }

}
```

I am almost sure that I have seen this before ... or at least discussion about it, but I can't find it.

Comment: You might rewrite the code with two scoped locks, leaving out the 'scoped_unlock'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for Boost.Threads [Reverse Lock](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.other_locks.reverse_lock):

> `reverse_lock` reverse the operations of a lock: it provide for RAII-style, that unlocks the lock at construction time and lock it at destruction time. In addition, it transfer ownership temporarily, so that the mutex can not be locked using the Lock.